# Extending a sheaf by zero outside a locally closed subspace

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Suppose $X$ is a locally closed subset of $Y$($X$can be expressed as an intersection of a closed set $F$and an open set $O$), $\mathcal{F}$ is a sheaf on Y, $\mathcal{F}|_X$ is its restriction on X, can we prove that there exists a unique sheaf $\mathcal{G}$ on $Y$ such that $\mathcal{F}|_{Y-X}$ is zero and $\mathcal{G}|_X=\mathcal{F}|_X$?

Comment: I would first extend $\mathcal{F}$ to $O$, and then that to $Y$. So if $i:X\rightarrow O$ and $j:O\rightarrow Y$, then $\mathcal{G}=j_!i_*\mathcal{F}$.

Comment: I verified that, it's right.Thanks! I found the result in Godement 's book, but I just cannot understand why the proof was so long.

Comment: You are welcome.:)